# Google Sheets XPath Query for XML namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, xquery

I'm trying to retrieve the last and second to last entries for the `date` element in the below example:

```
<c:classroom>Classroom 1</c:classroom>
    <a:date>2018-03-01</a:date>
    <a:teacher>Ms Smith</a:teacher>
    <a:assistant>Sara</a:assistant>
    <a:student>Rose</a:student>
    <a:student>Kris</a:student>
    <a:student>Jane</a:student>
<c:classroom>Classroom 2</c:classroom>
    <a:date>2018-03-02</a:date>
    <a:teacher>Mr Jones</a:teacher>
    <a:assistant>Bob</a:assistant>
    <a:student>Mike</a:student>
    <a:student>Pat</a:student>
    <a:student>Rick</a:student>
<c:classroom>Classroom 1</c:classroom>
    <a:date>2018-03-05</a:date>
    <a:teacher>Ms Smith</a:teacher>
    <a:assistant>Sara</a:assistant>
    <a:student>Rose</a:student>
    <a:student>Kris</a:student>
    <a:student>Jane</a:student>
<c:classroom>Classroom 2</c:classroom>
    <a:date>2018-03-06</a:date>
    <a:teacher>Mr Jones</a:teacher>
    <a:assistant>Bob</a:assistant>
    <a:student>Mike</a:student>
    <a:student>Pat</a:student>
    <a:student>Rick</a:student>
```

Using `//*[local-name() = 'date'][last()]` returns almost everything and using `//*[local-name() = 'date'][last()-1]` fails.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:  This XPath query is for use in Google Sheets.

Comment: This question should not be a duplicate as the linked references (which are very helpful) had been reviewed and Google Sheets doesn't accept all XQueries.  This was originally tagged with [tag:google-spreadsheet] and edited to explicitly state so.  Also, it seems neither reference uses a combination of `last()` and `position()` operators as @zx485 used.  Happy though to delete if SE still concludes it's a duplicate or doesn't contribute enough to stand alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath

```
(//*[local-name() = 'date'])[last() - position() &lt; 2]
```

This should get the last two `date`s in the document.

Comment: Thanks. The link was an interesting read.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This question is actually not a duplicate as the references (which are very helpful) had been reviewed and Google Sheets doesn't accept all XQueries; e.g. Google Sheets doesn't seem compatible with `&lt;` though `<` works.  Could you point out how to get a line break for between the dates?

Comment: The general approach is to `concat()` a `&#xa;` at the end of each node value. But I don't know what the google way of doing this is.